# How to use powershell in cmd to split string in file with out new line

Tags: winforms, powershell, cmd

I try to use CMD in windows to split some record form file
but output not in same line.

## list.csv

1,aa,bbb,0001,dsad
2,ab,aba,0002
3,bccc,asdd,0003,sdasd

Then I split with comma (,) with

```
powershell -NoProfile "(gc list.csv)   |%{"$($_.Split(',')[4,3])"}|out-File list2_split.csv"
```

## result

0001
bbb
0002
aba
0003
asdd

Are you have any idea to print with no new line?

## exsample

0001,bbb
0002,aba
0003,asdd

Comment: Why are you parsing manually instead of using [`Import-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6)?

Comment: In Windows Command Prompt directly (without PowerShell): `for /F "usebackq tokens=3,4 delims=, eol=," %I in ("list.csv") do @echo(%J,%I`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done in Windows Command Prompt directly (so [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), without [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)), using a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```cmd
for /F "usebackq tokens=3,4 delims=, eol=," %I in ("list.csv") do @echo(%J,%I
```

To write the result to another file, just do the following (that is [output redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)):

```cmd
(for /F "usebackq tokens=3,4 delims=, eol=," %I in ("list.csv") do @echo(%J,%I) > "list2_split.csv"
```

To use this code in a batch file, make sure to double all `%`-symbols of the `for` variables.

Comment: Thanks, but why can't write the result to file when execute in .bat file?

Answer (score 1):

while i agree that working with the CSV file *as a CSV file* would likely be a good idea, this uses your original method ... you had the wrong index numbers and didn't tell PoSh to join the items into a new, comma delimited string.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
1,aa,bbb,0001,dsad
2,ab,aba,0002
3,bccc,asdd,0003,sdasd
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$InStuff |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Split(',')[3, 2] -join ','
        }
```

output ...

```
0001,bbb
0002,aba
0003,asdd
```